# JSON-ify string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Are there any faster ways to JSON-ify a string? I first escaped manually, then tried json.dumps as suggested below, but can I somehow use repr() too?

```
import timeit, json

def escape_str(string):
    return string.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace('"', '\\"').replace("\b", "\\b").replace("\f", "\\f").replace("\n", "\\n").replace("\r", "\\r").replace("\t", "\\t")

data = "hello\nworld"
print(data)
print('"' + escape_str(data) + '"', timeit.timeit('''\'"\' + escape_str(data) + \'"\'''', globals=globals(), number=1000000))
print(repr(data), timeit.timeit('''json.dumps(data)''', globals=globals(), number=1000000))
print(repr(data), timeit.timeit('''repr(data)''', globals=globals(), number=1000000))

#Output:
#hello
#world
#"hello\nworld" 0.6119729009999999
#'hello\nworld' 0.490987237
#'hello\nworld' 0.12092886899999988
```

Comment: Okay, and you need to write that how many million times so that 0.6 seconds would matter to anyone?

Comment: It writes literally "hello\nworld" because that's what you _told_ it to do, when you put `.replace("\n", "\\n")` in the list of string replacements.

Comment: No, that is what I want. Not the other representation.

Comment: Why don't you use `json.dumps`?

Comment: Wait, you're avoiding the `json` module because it's too slow? Are you aware that JSON has different syntax than Python? So if you're handling arbitrary data, this'll break at some point.

Comment: @Nineteendo But if it doesn't work properly, ultimately the speed doesn't matter. Beware of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: In the end you'll need almost as many `replace()` calls for the `repr()` version as for the string version and speed will be identical

Comment: @Nineteendo No no, I'm saying, *if you're handling arbitrary data*, at some point a solution using `repr()` will produce invalid JSON, so it won't matter if it's fast when it's broken. You'll have downtime.

Comment: Anyone can implement `__repr__()` as he likes. The output is not guaranteed to be close to JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `json.dumps()`. It's faster than fiddling with it yourself.

Trying to make `repr()` output the same, I added a method `escape_repr()`:

```py
import timeit
import json

def escape_str(string):
    return string.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace('"', '\\"').replace("\b", "\\b").replace("\f", "\\f").replace("\n", "\\n").replace("\r", "\\r").replace("\t", "\\t")

def escape_repr(string):
    return string.replace("\"","\\\"").replace("'", "\"").replace("\\x08", "\\b").replace("\\x0c", "\\f")

data = "hello \n_\"_\\_\b_\f world"
print(data)
print(json.dumps(data), timeit.timeit('''json.dumps(data)''', globals=globals(), number=1000000))
print('"' + escape_str(data) + '"', timeit.timeit('''\'"\' + escape_str(data) + \'"\'''', globals=globals(), number=1000000))
print(escape_repr(repr(data)), timeit.timeit('''escape_repr(repr(data))''', globals=globals(), number=1000000))
```

Results:

```
"hello \n_\"_\\_\b_\f world" 0.5502998
"hello \n_\"_\\_\b_\f world" 0.9209655000000001
"hello \n_\"_\\_\b_\f world" 0.6323072999999999
```

So `json.dumps()` is not only the correct way of doing it, but also the fastest.

Comment: @Nineteendo: then this is a XY-issue. Maybe you want to tell us what you really want to do.

Comment: I guess I can't help because I don't know what RTON is and the repo doesn't explain it.

Comment: Then use fast_rtons.py - I don't understand anything. 17 seconds, for what? Is it fast, is it slow? How fast does it need to be? Why use Python for performance sensitive stuff in the first place?

Comment: Wait can I use json.dumps to dump a string? Thank you.